# How to prevent Spell checking code in MS Office?

Tags: documentation, microsoft-office

We use MS Office. Outlook for emails, Word for some documentation and I use OneNote a lot for my own note taking.

What bugs me is when I drop some code or use key words or even camel case into these apps the spell checking picks them up and I have red squiggles everywhere. Ignore is pretty much useless, so either I have to turn off Spell Check altogether start adding these to the custom dictionary.

What would be good is if I can use the Set Language function to mark a whole block of text to just not be spell checked. Has anyone found a nice solution to this or do you know of a blank dictionary is best to use?

I found using "Mohawk" kind of does that... might just use that for now. Maybe create a macro to switch between them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually create a style for `Code` and then in language settings for the style you can uncheck spelling and grammar.  Then you can apply whatever other settings you want as well, font, indentation, etc.

Comment: I do this too. If you assign a key sequence like Alt-4 to apply the style then markup is very quick. Select the block of text and press Alt-4.

Comment: Yes that works better. Thought there might have been a more natural way. Thanks.

Comment: It's really quite natural; you designate code as a particular kind of text, one that should not be spell checked. If you also set a particular font for that style, preferably a fixed width one, your notes will be a little clearer yet.

Comment: This only seems to work for "blocks" though -- that is, entire paragraphs (or table cells).  I've defined both character and paragraph level styles for "code" and the spelling errors only go away on text with the paragraph style applied.

Comment: I was able to make the spelling errors go away by selecting a language other than English (even though the words were English) and then checking **Do not check spelling or grammar**.