# disable spell check when sending code in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-office

Sometimes I send code (or stack traces) via email (Outlook) and it's very annoying to see the red spell check squigglies.  What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Is there an option to globally turn off spell checking (and the turn it on again after sending the message)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/153483/how-to-prevent-spell-checking-code-in-ms-office

Answer (score 18):

You can turn off spell checking for specific sections of text, such as code. These instructions are for Outlook 2013.

- Select the text for which you want spell checking turned off
- Display the Review tab of the ribbon
- Click on Language then Set Proofing Language
- The Language dialog box pops up
- Select *Do not check spelling or grammar*
- Click on OK

This removes the red squiggly lines from your code, but keeps checking spelling for the rest of your document.

Comment: This only seems to work for "blocks" i.e. entire paragraphs or table cells.  I've defined both character and paragraph level styles and the spelling errors only go away on text with the paragraph style applied.

Comment: I put the "Language" drop down menu to the quick access bar. Then I can skip your first two steps!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot of Settings]

Found this and had to share since I accidentally turned it on and it was difficult to find again later after I realized how annoying it was.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add those words to your [dictionary](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-words-to-your-spell-check-dictionary-HA010354289.aspx#BM9).

1. Open a mail message.
2. Click the File tab.
3. Click Options.
4. Click Mail, click Spelling and Autocorrect, and then click Proofing.
5. Make sure the Suggest from main dictionary only check box is cleared.
6. Click Custom Dictionaries.
7. In the Custom Dictionaries dialog box, for any custom dictionaries you want to use, make sure the check box next to each of those dictionaries is selected.

I'm sure you could easily enough build a script to generate the dictionary programmatically before you import it.

Comment: I have to add every possible symbol (variable, method, etc) I will ever possibly use in the future to the dictionary?

Comment: Adding every symbol to a custom dictionary is impractical.  He just wants to turn spell check off for certain messages.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found that if you click Cancel on the spell check dialog, I get a message that says "We haven't finished checking your spelling, send anyway?". If you select Yes, you will send the email with out it checking the rest of the document for spelling errors.

This is as close as I can see to the "Send as is" option in other mail clients that ignore spelling for the rest of the document.

It doesn't take away the red lines, but at least it lets you send with out having to ignore every error.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this is to create a new style the turn on "Do not check spelling or grammar" in the Language Pull Down
[image: Style Dialog]

Answer (score -1):

Select all test using Ctrl+A
Then Alt+U+U+R+L
and then enter.

Comment: Is this for a specific version of Outlook? In Outlook 2016 there is no "U" command available after ALT. Perhaps if you listed the commands/dialogs each of those hotkey letters was selecting in turn we could translate this command to other versions of Outlook.